Electron - Transfer logical from Main process to the Renderer process when click <a target="_blank"> in Main process
is there any ways to transfer the logical in Main process to Renderer process when we click  tag with target="_blank". I will call  tag is "Google" ("My link" will be another web page: Google or something else)
I have some logic to block user when click any link after user click to "Google". But I got some issue when apply those logics. It only works when I open new Renderer process by new BrowserWindow(). Not work by click  tag with target="_blank".

As you can see in the picture, the link when I type in the input and click "Go", will apply all logic because it has it's own logic:

But with clicking "Google" or "Baidu", they will not be affected logic like when open by click "Go"
And I'll give you some more picture:
This will apply block logic (it's renderer2Window)

But this will not (clicking Google or Baidu)

Thank you all guys!
